# why line cutting the points is showing same color in legend for different plots in r ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am mapping aesthetic to a shape and created a manual shape scale. But the line connecting the points showing same color in the legend for two different lines.

```
p <- ggplot(data=data_read) + stat_summary(colour="blue", fun.y=mean, 
       geom="line", size=1.0, aes(x=factor(x), y=A, group=1), show.legend=T) +
stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", aes(x=factor(x), y=A, shape="A"),
             size=5,col="black") +
stat_summary(colour="green", fun.y=mean, geom="line", size=1.0, aes(x=factor(x),
             y=B, group=1), show.legend=T) +
stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", aes(x=factor(x), y=B, shape="B"), 
             size=3, col="black") +
scale_shape_manual("title", values=c("A"="\U0394", "B"="*"))

p + theme(legend.position = c(0.5,0.5),
          legend.text = element_text(size = 15, colour = "black"), 
          legend.title = element_text(size = 15, colour = "black")) +
coord_cartesian(ylim = c(10,30), expand = FALSE) +
expand_limits(x=0, y=10)
```

My data file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/namrfqrv7uzkycm/datafile.csv?dl=0).

Comment: Instead of hard-coding line colors outside of `aes`, you need to map a data column to colour inside `aes` (or create "artificial" mappings to colour inside `aes` as you do for shape) in order get legend lines with colors that match the line colours in the plot. Also, although you haven't shown your data, it looks like your data is in "wide" form. If you convert it to "long" form, you'll likely need only one call to `stat_summary` for each geom and you'll be able to map to colour and shape using a data column, rather than the hard-coded mappings in your current code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. I created "artificial" mapping for colour inside `aes` and used `scale_colour_manual` to get line colour and to get legend line with colours that match the line